# Differentiating 따뜻하다 and 따스하다

Tags: vocabulary

Besides *따뜻하다* having an extra usage to describe personality, *따뜻하다* and *따스하다* both mean *warm*, at least that's what I found in my dictionary. Are these words interchangeable, or do they have nuances/different degrees of warmth, etc?

Answer (score 2):

There are differences.

The difference is that 따뜻하다 is simply descriptive or tangible without emotions involved while 따스하다 is sentimental or intangible and is usually more emotional.

Example: You can say 마음이 따스하다, but seldom 마음이 따뜻하다 since 마음 is intangible.

Ex: 홍차가 따뜻하다 instead of 따스하다 ! since 홍차(red tea) is tangible.

Comment: So, "body warming" vs heart warming, or (I suppose it's fine to use Chinese on this site for this purpose?) 温暖 vs 温馨, is that correct?

Comment: I think it is correct, but it needs to be confirmed by natives after all.